# Charles proxy fails on SSL Connect Method

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, iptables, charles-proxy

I have Android 4.3 forced to use Charles proxy via IPTABLES.
The charles certificate is installed on the phone.
I am able to capture normal SSL traffic like https websites in the browser.
All POST and GET methods seem to work fine.
In a particular app, it fails when using the SSL CONNECT method.

- URL: https://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/
- Status: Failed
- Failure: SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
- Response Code: - Protocol: HTTP/1.0
- Method: CONNECT

Comment: I faced this problem on iOS10. I just turn off Charles when logging in with Facebook.

Comment: As the failure message says.The CA is not trusted.It has to be trusted to monitor the ssl traffic

Answer (score 61):

From iOS 10.3 you also need to go to *Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings* and trust Charles certificate.

[image]

Comment: When Charles shows Http method as `CONNECT` or response code showing as `200 connection established` this above solution will work. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 22):

You can face with this problem at some applications like Facebook or Instagram.
Charles certificate doesn't work at some new apps because they are using a technique named as SSL-PINNING. First of all you have to break ssl-pinning system of application or you can instal old version of application then it sometimes works but we need a new solution about ssl pinning in order to record traffic for this kind of applications.

Answer (score 17):

as @Berkay Yıldız says, it probably using ssl/certificate pinning.

how to fix/avoid/disable ssl pinning?

the whole logic is:

**LEVEL 1**: for `normal http`：
core logic：

- PC：Mac/Windows

  - Charles set http proxy
  - set port
- app use Charles proxy

  - inside Wifi, set

    - host IP
    - port

Note：
computer side, MUST use `wired network`, **NOT** wireless, otherwise mobile side network not usable

**LEVEL 2**: for `encrypted https`：

- PC

  - install Charles root certificate

    - Mac：use `Key Chain` to trust Charles Root CA
  - Charles

    - `Enable SSL Proxying`

      - set location filter for your specific api address
- phone

  - app

    - install Charles Root CA

      - Note: type should select: `VPN and Application`

        - NOT select：WLAN
      - makesure certificate install successfully

        - `Trusted Credentials -> User`, can see installed Charles certificate

**LEVEL 3**: for SPECIAL `https` which using `ssl pinning`:

- Phone：

  - make sure root or jailbreak

    - Android：has rooted

      - for later to install tool: Xposed
    - iOS：has jail break

      - for later to install tool: Cydia
  - then install plugin/tool, capable of avoid/disable ssl pinning

    - Android：

      - [JustTrustMe](https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe) (based on [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer))
      - [Android-SSL-TrustKiller](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Android-SSL-TrustKiller) (Cydia Substrate)
    - iOS：

      - [SSL Kill Switch 2](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/ssl-kill-switch2) (based on Cydia)

        - old version：[iOS SSL Kill Switch](https://github.com/iSECPartners/ios-ssl-kill-switch) (based on Cydia)

---

more detailed summary please refer my post (written in Chinese): [1](http://www.crifan.com/mac_use_charles_capture_crawl_ios_android_phone_app_data_include_https_package) and [2](http://www.crifan.com/charles_cannot_crawl_parital_https_request_package_which_using_ssl_cerificate_pinning)

Comment: I am stuck with android app with SSL pinning, is there any Android Emulator rooted image i can use?

Comment: @Ish you can try `Nox Player`, which support `Xposed`, ![Nox Player Xposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXB7E.png)

Answer (score 9):

Some folks my end up here with android N Devices that won't do SSL over charles even after installing the cert - now on http://chls.pro/ssl

In N - you need to also add an xml file and security config.  This post goes into more details: [How to get charles proxy work with Android 7 nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat)

Comment: if it doesn't work after adding the security xml rules, its because youre not building in debug. You should either build for debug OR add: `android:debuggable="true"` to your <application> tag in your AndroidManifest

Comment: @Wikkle_A you are awesome.

Answer (score 6):

I have met the same problem. And after installing the latest certificate, it is solved.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

On your phone, visit http://charlesproxy.com/getssl to download the cert. Upon downloading the cert in android, it will prompt you to install the cert, give the cert a name and continue. It should now work.

Note: The sshould be similar on an iPhone

Answer (score 1):

I got the following error when I was trying to install the cert on my Nexus 6p, Android 6.0. (I followed the instructions in charles and downloaded the cert via http://chls.pro/ssl.):

> Couldn't install because the certificate file couldn't be read.

The solution  to this problem was to install via: 
`Settings` > `Security` > `Install from storage`
After navigating to the cert file and installing it everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this with an app using facebook login on an android phone, I got around it by uninstalling the fb app. Then the mobile fb web is used instead and I can charles everything. With the fb app installed the fb api fails with SSL error.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung phones, you should install the certificate by navigating to **Biometrics and security/Other security settings/Install from device storage/CA Certificate**.

Answer (score -1):

On this link http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/ you have all the information you need on properly installing the Charles certificate.

After installing it you'll get rid of the "SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca" error.

Answer (score -3):

I am using Charles 4.2.5 and Nexus 6P on Android 8.1.

One cannot use Charles to track https on my mobile phone.

Plz note that after Android N, we cannot capture normal SSL traffic of others'app.

Here is the official website of Charles.
[https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/](http://officlal%20website%20of%20Charles)

> Android As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in
>   order to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL
>   Proxying. This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps that
>   you control.
>
> In order to configure your app to trust Charles, you need to add a
>   Network Security Configuration File to your app. This file can
>   override the system default, enabling your app to trust user installed
>   CA certificates (e.g. the Charles Root Certificate). You can specify
>   that this only applies in debug builds of your application, so that
>   production builds use the default trust profile.
>
> Add a file res/xml/network_security_config.xml to your app:
>
> Then add a reference to this file in your app's manifest, as follows:
>
> ...

Comment: Wrong. For third-party apps, you can download the APK, use a tool to decompile the app, inject the right files into your app, recompile the app, then sideload the app.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Or just use xposed/magisk module