# Client TLS handshake failed. The client does not trust the proxy's certificate Android mitproxy

Tags: android, proxy, ca, man-in-the-middle

i am trying to get the JSON web token of the Be real request with mitproxy. but it always throws this error in the console:

Client TLS handshake failed. The client does not trust the proxy's certificate for mobile.bereal.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'sslv3 alert certificate unknown')]))

if looked into it a bit and it has something to do with ca certificates and stuff but i dont know  alot about this field.

tried to get 1 api request trought with an token so that i could than use that toke to send a request myself for the "homepage"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57568571/150978