How to perform security testing(Manual) of mobile application which is built on Flutter. Tools which are used for Android Flutter APK test
I would like to perform manual android security testing which is developed using Flutter.
Any suggestion of tools would be highly appreciated along with steps.
Tried using Burpsuit but traffic is not captured and I have installed CA certificate also on my android device.

What have you tried so far? Have you installed the root CA certificate correctly as system certificate or have you modified the APK to make sure the CA certificate is recognized? For details see e.g. my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570009/150978
