Android APK recording in JMeter via Android Studio Emulator
I have installed an Android emulator, where I have my application's APK installed (I can't disclose the APK name as it belongs to the IT company where I work).
I have successfully established a connection between JMeter, running locally, and the Android emulator. I followed all the necessary steps and I am able to record the traffic from the mobile browser (e.g., Chrome).
However, when I try to record the mobile application, I encounter the following error screen.
Mobile application error screen
Do I need to follow additional steps in order to record the traffic of mobile apk.
Can someone please guide me.
Thank you.
I have tried adding Jmeter rootCA certificate in wifi additional settings window.
Also added the certificate in security/privacy tab in android settings

Android apps by default don't trust user installed CA certificates. You have to explicitly enable that. For details see my answer on a similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570009/150978

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In addition to installing JMeter's MITM certificate you will also need to amend Android network security configuration and edit your application manifest in order to allow trusting user-installed certificates

In the application tag of your application manifest add the following line:
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"


Create network_security_config.xml file in your application resources folder and put the following snippet there:

Re-compile your application in debug mode

Install the debug .apk file onto your emulator


More information:

Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording
and Configuring an Android device to work with Burp Suite

