# Reverse engineering app modifying the apk to accept the certificate

Tags: android, apk, mitmproxy

I've been trying to get the api endpoints and routes of an app from the Play Store, so far I've tried:

- Using **mitmproxy without root**: rejects the user's certificate (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2054)
- Running the app on multiple rooted and non-rooted **android emulators**: says the integrity check has failed due to rooting or similar. Rooting and installing rootcloack seems not to help.

---

- Modifying the .APK to accept the user certicate using https://github.com/levyitay/AddSecurityExceptionAndroid as said here: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2054#issuecomment-289206209

I'm getting the APK from https://apkcombo.com/, which downloads a .zip with multiple APKs (`com.[appname].app.apk`, `config.es.apk`, ...) I unzip it, run https://github.com/levyitay/AddSecurityExceptionAndroid on `com.[appname].app.apk` and then I zip it again and try to install it using https://apkcombo.com/es-es/how-to-install/, but it gives me this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CIdO.png

I've looked into some tutorials to sign the .apk, but I think I'm doing something wrong as the error keeps popping, sometimes it's another error about a missing certificate.

So, **how can I modify the apk to accept the user certificate correctly**?

---

I'm also trying to get the api endpoints by decompiling the app, but the code seems really obfuscated.

Comment: firstly this doesn't sound legal or correct, because if the app on the store wanted you to have this information, surely they would have made it public. secondly, you've listed a whole bunch of problems here but what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear, the question is: how can I modify the apk to accept the user certificate correctly?

Comment: Use `apktool` to decompile the app (you can disable sources decompilation, you only need resources) and then apply this one: [How to add network security configuration to enable Charles proxy SSL in Nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879181/how-to-add-network-security-configuration-to-enable-charles-proxy-ssl-in-nougat) For signing an apk use `apksigner` from AndroidSDK build tools.